# how to create an InfluxDB user in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, influxdb

I'm having trouble creating an InfluxDB user in a dockerfile.  I want the dockerfile to also install and start `influxd`.  For postgres I can use this in my Dockerfile after installing postgres:

`RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER matt WITH PASSWORD 'test123';" &&\
    createdb test_db &&\
    psql --command "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test_db TO matt;"`

Is there an equivalent for influxdb?

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately used pieces of the [tutumcloud/influxdb repo](https://github.com/tutumcloud/influxdb/tree/a098ee6fa35aae7692748f5c1b0bd3e26fbb77fd/1.0): the dockerfile starts a shell script that, when it runs, starts `influxd` in the background, creates an admin user and then foregrounds the `influxd` process.

Comment: can you share the script ? @Matt